# Tablelayoutlooses inner TableRows after call subintent

Tags: android, android-layout, tablelayout, xoom

I have a form with a lot of fields. After call a new Intent (camera) and back to main activity, all fields are filled. OK.

But tablelayout looses inner TableRows. Why? Is there no way to keep tablerows?

```
tableMaterialObra = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tlMaterialObra);
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
tr.addView(cb);
tableMaterialObra.addView(tr);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create TableLayout in oncreate() method and donot do anything in onResume() method then none of the row will be lost

### SampleCode

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ActivityGroup;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RelativeLayoutTesting extends ActivityGroup implements OnClickListener{
    TextView choosenGroup;
    android.widget.RelativeLayout currentView = null;
    ArrayList<String> logpoint = null;
    TableLayout tableMaterialObra;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );


        // set the relative layout as our view 
        setContentView(R.layout.my_table);
        tableMaterialObra = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.my_table);
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
        tr.addView(cb);
        tableMaterialObra.addView(tr);
        LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
        myLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        startActivity(new Intent(RelativeLayoutTesting.this, com.sunil.MyListView.class));
    }

}
```

Comment: TableLayout and respectives TableRows are already on onCreate. And onResume method is not implemented (@Override)




To call the new Intent:

`Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
     startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 0);`

Comment: check whether you are doing anything in onActivityResult. i have tried the same exampe that i have given you for startActivityForResult. its working fine

Comment: `@Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (data.getExtras()!=null && data.getExtras().containsKey("data")) {
   Bitmap imagem = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
   
//...   
   TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tlFotos);

   LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
   TableRow row = (TableRow) inflater.inflate(R.layout.foto_tablerow,null);

   ((CheckBox) row.getChildAt(0)).setTag(id);
   ((ImageView) row.getChildAt(1)).setImageBitmap(imagem);
   
   tl.addView(row);

  }
 }`

Just it.

Comment: The code above runs without any exception. Thanks for your time.